# Getting and storing position of PanoramaView before changing VC

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, viewcontroller, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm trying to learn Google Map API and i'm building an app that have two `UIViewController`. Root `UIViewController` loads a Google Street View Panorama as shown below:

```
@IBOutlet weak var viewStreet: UIView!
var panoView: GMSPanoramaView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let panoView = GMSPanoramaView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height))
    panoView.delegate = self
    panoView.moveNearCoordinate(CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: -33.732, longitude: 150.312))

    viewStreet.addSubview(panoView)
    viewStreet.sendSubviewToBack(panoView)
 }
```

I have added a `UIButton` that loads another `UIViewController`, and I'm willing to add a "Back" button to get back to the first one. Using segues it works fine but  `panoView` is always loaded at  `latitude: -33.732, longitude: 150.312`, as i have initializated it. What i'm trying to achieve is getting back to the lat/long of the last panorama loaded before switching to the second VC, for instance:

viewDidLoad -> lat. x1, long. y1;

moving to another panorama -> lat. x2, long. y2;

changing `UIViewController`;

back to root VC, panorama lat. and long. should be (x2, y2).

Using `didMoveToPanorama` method i can get panoID every time PanoramaView changes, the problem is storing it when VC changes. May i use `NSUserDefaults` or is there a better way? Here is code:

```
 func panoramaView(view: GMSPanoramaView, didMoveToPanorama panorama: GMSPanorama?) {
    panoID = panorama!.panoramaID
}
```

Note that method `didMoveToPanorama:nearCoordinate:` can't be used since it is called only when Panorama has moved due to `moveNearCoordinate`

On a side note, i've edited title cause it was misleading, and improved post with further informations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an easier way to achieve this:

In Main.storyboard: Show segue to "SecondViewController"

In SecondViewController.swift:

```
@IBAction func backToPreviousVC(sender: AnyObject) {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

This way viewDidLoad is not called and it get back to the last panorama seen.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is storing latitude and longitude values before changing controller, then restore them as something like this :

```
CGFloat latitudeSave;
CGFloat longitudeSave;

-(void) viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    latitudeSave = -33.732; //save current coordonates here (use panoView current values)
    longitudeSave = 150.312;
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [panoView moveNearCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitudeSave, longitude: longitudeSave)]; //not sure of this line 
}
```

Comment: Ty, but like this i can only save one static lat/long, while i need to save the last ones before VC changes. I was not clear maybe, pardon but english is not my native language, now i've edited the post providing a more accurate request and more code. If you manage to fix code in order to get panoID or lat/long of the last panorama loaded i can mark this as accepted answer.

Comment: I don't think that giving down vote is a good way to ask for further help... I agree that you wasn't clear.

Comment: Didn't give down vote, i appreciated your effort. Just look at my rep, till 15 i can't up or down vote. Deleting this as soon as you read. :)

Comment: Ok my bad, I'll try to help you ASAP, but I have no knowledge of Google Map API so it will be hard to help more...

Comment: No probl, i'll try to solve this my way too. If successfull i'm gonna edit your post into swift and marking it as accepted answer, so that no one loses rep and we're set. ;)

Comment: Got it, pardon, i'm quite new to the site.

Comment: @DonG Then welcome to SO! You'll enjoy it. Just remember: we vote on the quality of the questions and answers themselves, we don't vote to thank or to punish users. :) Thanks.

Comment: @EricD Thanks for clarification. Indeed, I didn't noticed that the question was targeting Swift. Really sorry.